# NoReverseMatch Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In Django I have a class based view:

```
class ApiRoot(APIView):
  def get(request, format=None):
    return Response({
      'users': reverse('user-list', request=request, format=format),
      #'snippets': reverse('snippet-list', request=request, format=format)
    })
```

and the following url patterns in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns([
    url(r'^$', views.ApiRoot.as_view(), name='api-root'),
    url(r'^snippets/$', views.SnippetList.as_view(), name='snippet-list'),
    url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.SnippetDetail.as_view(), name='snippet-detail'),
    url(r'^users/$', views.UserList.as_view(), name='user-list'),
    url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.UserDetail.as_view(), name='user-detail'),
])
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls',
                           namespace='rest_framework')),
```

I think I wired up things properly but I get the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'user-list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'format': <rest_framework.request.Request object at 0x7f99998c4c50>}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: [u'users\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', 'users/$']
```

Any Idea why?

thanks

Comment: `'users': reverse('user-list')` is enough

Comment: Sweet, it works. So the tutorial is wrong

Comment: I will add the suggestion as response, i will appreciate your up vote. Thanks

Comment: Sorry if the vote came a bit late ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should reverse the url as `reverse('user-list')`. That should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this while following this same drf tutorial but it was because of something else. I actually did not have any names on my endpoints. The `urlpatterns` inside my `snippets/urls.py` file looked like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.api_root),
    path('snippets/', views.SnippetList.as_view()),
    path('snippets/<int:pk>/', views.SnippetDetail.as_view()),
    path('users/', views.UserList.as_view()),
    path('users/<int:pk>/', views.UserDetail.as_view())
]
```

And, my `root_api` method looked like this:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'users': reverse('user-list', request=request, format=format),
        'snippets': reverse('snippet-list', request=request, format=format)
    })
```

So, the code was trying to search for endpoints named `user-list` and `snippet-list` but it could not find them because no endpoint in the `snippets/urls.py` was named. So, I updated the `urlpatterns` like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.api_root, name='root'),
    path('snippets/', views.SnippetList.as_view(), name='snippet-list'),
    path('snippets/<int:pk>/', views.SnippetDetail.as_view(), name='snippet-detail'),
    path('users/', views.UserList.as_view(), name='user-list'),
    path('users/<int:pk>/', views.UserDetail.as_view(), name='user-detail')
]
```

And it worked. I hope this would help someone.